# Spring security mvcMatchers

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat9

I am learning spring-security and created simple application to learn matchers. Unfortunately, I cannot get `mvcMatchers` to work. The other thing is that it works perfectly with `antMatchers`. Please see it's source below.
1) dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
     <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2) MvcWebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[]{SecurityConfig.class};
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { MvcWebConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}
```

3) MvcWebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example.controller")
public class MvcWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   @Bean
   public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
      SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
      templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
      templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
      return templateResolver;
   }

   @Bean
   public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
      SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
      templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
      templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
      return templateEngine;
   }

   @Override
   public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
      ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
      resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
      registry.viewResolver(resolver);
   }
}
```

4) SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/secured/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            //.mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/secured/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
}
```

5) SecurityWebInitializer:

```
public class SecurityWebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

6) MyController

```
@Controller
public class MyController { 
    @GetMapping("unsecured")
    public String unsecured(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Unsecured");
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("secured/msg")
    public String secured(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Secured");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

7) index.html is just simple Themeleaf template to output message

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
   <p th:text="${message}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I package app as war, deploy it to Tomcat 9 application server, and open `warname/unsecured` and `warname/secured/msg` URLs and it works as expected (unsecured just outputs message 'unsecured', secured asks for login/password. After logging in it displays page with message 'secured'). When I comment `antMatchers` and uncomment `mvcMatchers` in `SecurityConfig` navigating to any of these 2 urls gives me standard 404 Tomcat page. I tried to provide `mvcMatchers` with different patterns, such as: `/secured/msg`, `/secured/msg/`, `secured/msg`, `/secured/msg/*`, and every time I got 404. While remote debugging of app I have found that it seems that `mvcMatcher.match` is not get called, while `antMatcher.match` is called during attemt to access `warname/secured/msg` page. Can you please tell me how I can make app to work with `mvcMatchers` the same way as it works now with `antMatchers`?

Answer (score 0):

Try add annotation `@PreAuthorized("hasRole('ADMIN')")` abow your endpoints like this:

```
@PreAuthorized("hasRole('ADMIN')") 
            @GetMapping("secured/msg")
                public String secured(Model model) {
                    model.addAttribute("message", "Secured");
                    return "index";
                }
```

btw. You should use direct paths in mvcMatchers like:

```
mvcMatchers(HttpMeethod.GET, "/secured/msg"...)
```